# Wavelength of "complementary colours"?

Tags: optics, visible-light, wavelength

In physics/chemistry/the life sciences there's a common experimental method of determining the concentration of a sample using [spectrophotometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometry). We can measure the [absorbance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbance#Beer-Lambert_law) of the sample at a particular wavelength, and use Beer-Lambert's law to determine the concentration.

Normally, the wavelength at which absorbance is most pronounced is the one corresponding to the colour that is "complementary" to the colour we see, as shown in the chart below.

[image]

My question is, is there a way to mathematically define the "complementary wavelength" of some colour in the visible spectrum, or is the notion of complementary colours merely an empirical one?

Comment: The complementary colors are related to properties of the human retinal cone cells, not really to anything related the the light.

Comment: The complementary color is a mix of all wavelengths except for the one that was absorbed - so by definition it doesn't have a single wavelength.

Comment: There are colors in the Violet area that don't have a single frequency at all - they can only be made by combinations of two or more frequencies.

Comment: It's the colour that stimulates your eyeballs the opposite way of another colour. Some people with a lot of patience did empirically figure out the properties of the human visual system a long time ago, and that's how we got those CIE colour charts like the one in JEB's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Light of a particular wavelength may perhaps be considered to have a particular color (but in color perception, context matters). But there is no inverse mapping from color to wavelength. Most colors represent a mixture of wavelengths, not even unique. Different mixtures may produce the same color.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing in Maxwell's equation that allows us to define complementary colors. (QCD, tho....?).

The empirical thing is called the 1931 CIE color space (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space)
which has:

[image]

which you can poke around with this as a guide:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on the QCD part? Or is it just a cute reference to color charge?

Comment: QCD is Quantum chromodynamics but has nothing to do with "real" colours that we talk about day-to-day.  It describes the interactions of quarks (sub atomic particles) via the strong force.  I think it was a tongue-in-cheek reference.

Comment: Is it fair to say that a complementary color would be found by drawing a straight line through the center/white point "E" on the CIE diagram, or is it more complex than that?

Comment: @MarkRansom that's up to you.

Comment: Well that's the point, it's *not* up to me.  There should be an objective standard.  I'm just wondering if that would qualify.  It seems you have no opinion on that.

Comment: The complementary colour would be the one that is white light minus a particular wavelength. I would expect that to be what you get by reflecting through the white point "E", but I'm not a colour scientist (that's a real thing). Note that "E" isn't necessarily the colour of your laboratory lighting so that might not apply. I think it's the  colour of daylight, or some kind of neutral point of human vision (which is adapted for daylight).